# Multiple conditions for ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, boolean

I have the following table with 3 checkboxes. I assigned each one its own model.

I have a button which I want to be disabled unless any one of the 3 checkbox models are true.

However I'm confused since I expected to use

`<button " ng-disabled="!mt0 || !mt1 || !mt2">Reassign</button>`

since if **any** of those were to be true the button should not be disabled.

However, the *opposite* worked:

`<button  ng-disabled="!mt0 && !mt1 && !mt2">Reassign</button>`

Why?

See plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yURa3g0aNjDyfEvjK2D0?p=preview

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this to achieve what you want: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bc24nau/1/)

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mt0">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mt1">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mt2">
    <button ng-disabled=" (mt0||mt1||mt2) ?  false : true">Reassign</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Very simple `ng-disable="true"` means disable the button.

Now suppose all mt0,mt1,mt2 are true

```
mt0 || mt1 || mt2==true
```

then it will disable the button

even any of them true makes above condition true and disable the button.

`!mt0 || !mt1 || !mt2==false` if everything is true and will not disable the button.

but any of them true makes above condition true and disable the button.

`mt0 && mt1 && mt2==true` if everything is true and will disable the button

but any of them false makes above condition false and not disable the button.

`!mt0 && !mt1 && !mt2==false` if everything is true and not disable the button

but any of them false makes above condition false and  disable the button.

Comment: I think your last sentence  is incorrect.  See http://plnkr.co/edit/yURa3g0aNjDyfEvjK2D0?p=preview

Only way it works for me is `<button  ng-disabled="!mt0 && !mt1 && !mt2">Reassign</button>`

Answer (score 2):

`ng-disabled="true"` will cause the button to be disabled.

With `mt0 || mt1 || mt2`, if any are true, then the expression evaluates to true, so if any are true, the button is disabled.

Instead of saying "disabled unless", it's easier to say "disabled when". You want the button **disabled when** all the properties are false. You need `false && false && false`, so `!mt0 && !mt1 && !mt2` makes sense!

Comment: Except I just changed the plunker as above and now it works in reverse as it should.

Comment: @m59 this does not achieve what OP wants: > I have a button which I want to be disabled unless any one of the 3 checkbox models are true. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bc24nau/)

Comment: @Mikey true that. I updated my answer with a decent explanation. I think the OP's expression is good. It's just easier to think about expressions like that when you use the right wording (disabled when vs disabled unless).

Answer (score 0):

simply, write true or false without ' '

```
ng-disabled="condition1==true && condition2==true"
```

or

```
ng-disabled="variable1==true && variable2==true"
```